# tf31003 on VS2012 Windows8 (worked well on VS2010 on Windows 7)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, tfs

I just reinstalled my laptop on Windows 8 and VS2012 but now i can't connect to a private TFS server but it work well on my desktop with Windows 7 and VS2010.

For a lot of people this problem was solved by clearing IE cookies, but it don't work for me.

Comment: Can you access the TFS web interface?

Comment: from my desktop yes, not from my laptop

Comment: It doesn't prompt you for any credentials? can you get a ping to the server? telnet on 8080/relevant port?

Comment: it prompt me for credentials but my login is rejected, and I can ping the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would contact the TFS administrator and check how authentication is configured on the server. 
Also, be sure to use your full domain name(e.g DOMAIN_NAME\USER_NAME).

I don't believe this has anything to do with the browser implementation you decide to use.